# Four-Letter Blocks: Pop Music (13x13)

Tags: crosswords, jigsaw-puzzle

I've designed a new type of puzzle called [Four-Letter Blocks](https://donkirkby.github.io/four-letter-blocks/) that mixes crossword puzzles with jigsaw puzzles. You are given a crossword puzzle that's been filled in and then cut up into blocks of four letters, as well as the usual set of crossword clues. Use the clues to assemble the grid. The bad news is that the clues aren't numbered in the normal way - 1 Across might not be in the top left. The good news is that every word has at least the first letter given. For large puzzles like today's, each corner uses a different suit for the clues.

At 13x13, today's challenge is at the hard level, try my previous puzzles for an [easy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/111376/38) introduction or [medium](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/111441/38) challenge. You can either print out this page or the [PDF version](https://donkirkby.github.io/four-letter-blocks/images/music-13x13.pdf), or download the image and solve it in a paint program. Gluing onto cardboard or felt will make the pieces easier to work with.

[image: Pieces of a crossword puzzle]

Across
**4♣.** Scratch or spoil
**5♣.** Bagel snacks
**6♣.** Larry, Curly, or Moe
**9♣.** Spiderweb's gem
**1♢.** Beatles' forbidden transaction (4 words)
**3♢.** Bassoon's little brother
**6♢.** Farmyard humbug
**7♢.** Big fellow who's up to no good
**8♢.** Geological layer
**9♢.** Groucho wondered if it would play there
**10♢.** Fraternal order with a deer leader?
**11♢.** Mrs. Danny DeVito
**1♡.** Our closest star
**2♡.** Elton John's reptilian wriggle (2 words)
**6♡.** Smart fashion choices
**8♡.** Providence protects children and ___
**9♡.** Swear word
**11♡.** Keith from the big city
**14♡.** Monty Python's dead bird
**16♡.** Geological period
**18♡.** Trap like a small animal
**19♡.** Work the soil
**3♠.** Russian emperor
**5♠.** South Korea's first president
**9♠.** Lawrence of Arabia lead
**11♠.** Internet business

Down
**1♣.** "At Last" singer James
**2♣.** Leslie who played Aaron Burr
**3♣.** Make me laugh
**7♣.** Suzanne, singer of "Tom's Diner"
**8♣.** Big-mouth jug
**1♢.** Deal with it
**2♢.** Cain's doomed brother
**4♢.** Medical clinic or condiment
**5♢.** Comfy corner
**3♡.** Holds grain or missile
**4♡.** Contents of a cast
**5♡.** That's a negative
**6♡.** Compact storage for music
**7♡.** Scent
**9♡.** Simpsons bus driver
**10♡.** Stage whisper (1 word) or one fourth of a square (2 words)
**11♡.** Often mixed with downs
**12♡.** Ship deserter
**13♡.** Is that a phone in your pocket, or are you just cold?
**15♡.** Italian before Euros
**17♡.** Totally pipe shaped, man!
**1♠.** Pretend to be one of the 4♡ Down
**2♠.** Fish eggs
**3♠.** Heavy kind of rain
**4♠.** Colourful part of London or New York
**6♠.** Guinness, the original Obiwan
**7♠.** Stronger than 7♡ Down
**8♠.** Netherlands
**10♠.** Ambulance letters
**12♠.** Boohoo!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solved puzzle (including suits and clue numbers):

> [image: 13×13 filled crossword grid]