# Four-Letter Blocks: Nursery Rhymes (15x15)

Tags: crosswords, jigsaw-puzzle

I've designed a new type of puzzle called [Four-Letter Blocks](https://donkirkby.github.io/four-letter-blocks/) that mixes crossword puzzles with jigsaw puzzles. You are given a crossword puzzle that's been filled in and then cut up into blocks of four letters, as well as the usual set of crossword clues. Use the clues to assemble the grid. The bad news is that the clues aren't numbered in the normal way - 1 Across might not be in the top left. The good news is that every word has at least the first letter given. For large puzzles like today's, each corner uses a different suit for the clues.

At 15x15, today's challenge is at the expert level, and it's the finale in my series of puzzles. Try the previous puzzles for an [easy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/111376/38), [medium](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/111441/38), or [hard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/111520/38) challenge. You can either print out this page or the [PDF version](https://donkirkby.github.io/four-letter-blocks/images/nursery-15x15.pdf), or download the image and solve it in a paint program. Gluing onto cardboard or felt will make the pieces easier to work with.

[image: Pieces of a crossword puzzle]

Across
**2♣.** Dug like a pig
**4♣.** Isn't it obvious?
**5♣.** Couldn't get her poor dog a bone
**6♣.** Pair of hill climbers (3 words)
**7♣.** Bond, not James Bond
**8♣.** Chocolate or golden dog, for short
**9♣.** Not fauna
**10♣.** Turn a plane sideways
**12♣.** Swallowed by a whale
**15♣.** "Get 'em!"
**17♣.** Wife of Zeus
**3♢.** Jacob's hairy brother
**5♢.** T, in a sorority
**7♢.** Old woman who lived ___ ___ shoe
**10♢.** Lovelace, the first computer programmer
**11♢.** Frozen waffle
**14♢.** Fleece as white as ___
**15♢.** The days of Mother Goose
**2♡.** Honest Mr. Lincoln
**7♡.** Change or newfangled, for short
**8♡.** Modern Persia
**9♡.** Notions
**10♡.** What Miss Muffet said to the spider
**12♡.** Made a mistake
**13♡.** Three, four, knock at the ___
**14♡.** What the king called for after his pipe and bowl
**17♡.** Funny Caesar
**18♡.** What 6♣ Across went to fetch
**20♡.** Bitter chocolate or bitter comedy
**21♡.** Original language spoken in 14♡ Down
**2♠.** Where Cleopatra sailed her barge
**3♠.** Soap ingredient
**6♠.** Snakey fish
**9♠.** Lots of energy
**10♠.** Tribute poem
**11♠.** Rubber around a British wheel

Down
**1♣.** Measures a corner
**3♣.** Portuguese greeting
**11♣.** Q follower
**12♣.** LBJ's predecessor
**13♣.** What a sentence is about (abbr.)
**14♣.** Kids dream of a 64 pack from them
**15♣.** Got rid of a small building?
**16♣.** Who Canadians stand on guard for
**1♢.** With the least strength
**2♢.** Commercial messages
**4♢.** Hope to get on a flight (2 words)
**6♢.** Orange coat
**8♢.** Without the most common vowel (2 words)
**9♢.** The proverbial beaver
**12♢.** Trimmed or took small steps
**13♢.** Saying "You've got mail" since 1989
**14♢.** Talk like a drunk
**15♢.** Honolulu's island
**16♢.** On the frontlines of a chess board
**1♡.** Not well
**3♡.** What Old McDonald hears here and there
**4♡.** Hawaiian necklace
**5♡.** Wouldn't take no for an answer
**6♡.** Approves without speaking
**7♡.** Centre
**11♡.** Lowest price
**14♡.** A place for Internet users to discuss things
**15♡.** Famous potatoes
**16♡.** Shakespearean actor
**18♡.** Sassy
**19♡.** Child pirate?
**1♠.** Grinder, sometimes powered by wind
**4♠.** What Bo Peep lost
**5♠.** Thin layer of paper or wood
**7♠.** A very long time
**8♠.** A trip to Mecca
**10♠.** Facing away
**12♠.** Spain's longest river

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was quite a challenge! The final grid should look like this (suits indicated in the corners):

> [image: Solved grid]

My entry point:

> FIDDLERS THREE was the most useful long word to construct first, followed by MOTHER HUBBARD, JACK AND JILL and PAIL OF WATER. It was then a case of building words off these and seeking out shapes that were needed to fill 'dead ends'. (Still, it took about an hour and a half to complete the puzzle, including formatting the solution grid in Excel as I went along...)

A full list of clues matched to answers:

> **Across:**
>  2♣. Dug like a pig **NOSED**
>  4♣. Isn't it obvious? **DUH**
>  5♣. Couldn't get her poor dog a bone **MOTHER HUBBARD**
>  6♣. Pair of hill climbers (3 words) **JACK AND JILL**
>  7♣. Bond, not James Bond **GLUE**
>  8♣. Chocolate or golden dog, for short **LAB**
>  9♣. Not fauna **FLORA**
>  10♣. Turn a plane sideways **YAW**
>  12♣. Swallowed by a whale **JONAH**
>  15♣. "Get 'em!" **SIC**
>  17♣. Wife of Zeus **HERA**
>  3♢. Jacob's hairy brother **ESAU**
>  5♢. T, in a sorority **TAU**
>  7♢. Old woman who lived ___ ___ shoe **IN A**
>  10♢. Lovelace, the first computer programmer **ADA**
>  11♢. Frozen waffle **EGGO**
>  14♢. Fleece as white as ___ **SNOW**
>  15♢. The days of Mother Goose **OLDEN**
>  2♡. Honest Mr. Lincoln **ABE**
>  7♡. Change or newfangled, for short **MOD**
>  8♡. Modern Persia **IRAN**
>  9♡. Notions **IDEAS**
>  10♡. What Miss Muffet said to the spider **EEK**
>  12♡. Made a mistake **ERRED**
>  13♡. Three, four, knock at the ___ **DOOR**
>  14♡. What the king called for after his pipe and bowl **FIDDLERS THREE**
>  17♡. Funny Caesar **SID**
>  18♡. What 6♣ Across went to fetch **PAIL OF WATER**
>  20♡. Bitter chocolate or bitter comedy **DARK**
>  21♡. Original language spoken in 14♡ Down **LATIN**
>  2♠. Where Cleopatra sailed her barge **NILE**
>  3♠. Soap ingredient **LYE**
>  6♠. Snakey fish **EEL**
>  9♠. Lots of energy **OOMPH**
>  10♠. Tribute poem **ODE**
>  11♠. Rubber around a British wheel **TYRE**
>
>  **Down:**
>  1♣. Measures a corner **ANGLE**
>  3♣. Portuguese greeting **OLA**
>  11♣. Q follower **ANON**
>  12♣. LBJ's predecessor **JFK**
>  13♣. What a sentence is about (abbr.) **SUBJ.**
>  14♣. Kids dream of a 64 pack from them **CRAYOLA**
>  15♣. Got rid of a small building? **SHED**
>  16♣. Who Canadians stand on guard for **THEE**
>  1♢. With the least strength **WEAKEST**
>  2♢. Commercial messages **ADS**
>  4♢. Hope to get on a flight (2 words) **STAND BY**
>  6♢. Orange coat **RIND**
>  8♢. Without the most common vowel (2 words) **NO E**
>  9♢. The proverbial beaver **EAGER**
>  12♢. Trimmed or took small steps **EDGED**
>  13♢. Saying "You've got mail" since 1989 **AOL**
>  14♢. Talk like a drunk **SLUR**
>  15♢. Honolulu's island **OAHU**
>  16♢. On the frontlines of a chess board **PAWNS**
>  1♡. Not well **BADLY**
>  3♡. What Old McDonald hears here and there **BAA**
>  4♡. Hawaiian necklace **LEI**
>  5♡. Wouldn't take no for an answer **ORDERED**
>  6♡. Approves without speaking **NODS**
>  7♡. Centre **MID**
>  11♡. Lowest price **FREE**
>  14♡. A place for Internet users to discuss things **FORUM**
>  15♡. Famous potatoes **IDAHO**
>  16♡. Shakespearean actor **OLIVIER**
>  18♡. Sassy **PERT**
>  19♡. Child pirate? **KIDD**
>  1♠. Grinder, sometimes powered by wind **MILL**
>  4♠. What Bo Peep lost **SHEEP**
>  5♠. Thin layer of paper or wood **PLY**
>  7♠. A very long time **AEON**
>  8♠. A trip to Mecca **HAJ**
>  10♠. Facing away **OUTWARD**
>  12♠. Spain's longest river **EBRO**