# Four-Letter Blocks: Board Games (11x11)

Tags: crosswords, jigsaw-puzzle

I designed a puzzle called [Four-Letter Blocks](https://donkirkby.github.io/four-letter-blocks/) that mixes crossword puzzles with jigsaw puzzles. You are given a crossword puzzle that's been filled in and then cut up into blocks of four letters, as well as the usual set of crossword clues. Use the clues to assemble the grid. The bad news is that the clues aren't numbered in the normal way - 1 Across might not be in the top left. The good news is that every word has at least the first letter given.

At 11x11, today's challenge is at the medium level, try [Classic Toys (9x9)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/111376/38) for an easy introduction. You can either print out this page or the [PDF version](https://donkirkby.github.io/four-letter-blocks/images/board-games-11x11.pdf), or download the image and solve it in a paint program. Gluing onto cardboard or felt will make the pieces easier to work with.

Across
**2.** A soldier shouldn't leave home without it
**3.** Wear out
**4.** Make your lips match the music
**5.** Do ___ others
**7.** King's address
**8.** Applications
**10.** Compact source of music
**11.** Sine qua non
**12.** Tempted an angler
**13.** Nixon's dog
**14.** Joins the play
**16.** Buffy Summers
**18.** Long for the forest
**19.** Standout performances
**21.** A vote in favour
**22.** A bird's width
**25.** Sabbath
**26.** When you can't stop the four horsemen

Down
**1.** Bonnets, beanies, and berets
**2.** Joined with rings
**4.** One twelfth of AA
**6.** Bird homes
**9.** Stray from the path of rectitude
**15.** Furnishings
**16.** How some cities grow
**17.** Say you're in bed when you're not
**20.** Scottish girl or famous dog
**23.** Jedi master
**24.** Chewed by a cow
**27.** Prevention worth a pound of cure
**28.** A long story or the worst failure
**29.** Lost with your marbles?
**30.** How to win Trivial Pursuit
**31.** King's messenger
**32.** Himalayan myth
**33.** 4 Down on a ladder
**34.** Patella's home
**35.** Iron oxide

[image: Pieces of a crossword puzzle]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the completed grid:

> [image: 11×11 grid of words, divided into tetrominoes]
>
>  The "board game" theme is from CHECKERS (the classic game also called draughts) and WINGSPAN (an engine-building game by Stonemaier Games).